# Google's Custom Search API is an example of SOA and is NOT Restful

Tags: javascript, rest, soa

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS:

> HATEOAS, an abbreviation for Hypermedia as the Engine of Application
>   State, is a constraint of the REST application architecture that
>   distinguishes it from most other network application architectures.
>   The principle is that a client interacts with a network application
>   entirely through hypermedia provided dynamically by application
>   servers. A REST client needs no prior knowledge about how to interact
>   with any particular application or server beyond a generic
>   understanding of hypermedia. Contrast this with e.g. a
>   service-oriented architecture (SOA), where clients and servers
>   interact through a fixed interface shared through documentation or an
>   interface description language (IDL).

http://kinderman.net/2010/06/23/approaching-pure-rest-learning-to-love-hateoas:

> The Twitter API, for example, has services that allow clients to
>   update their status, or retweet one that already exists. Twitter's API
>   is not RESTful, so the documentation for retweeting a status instructs
>   developers to call the service by sending an HTTP POST or PUT request
>   to http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/[id].[format].
>
> If the Twitter API were RESTful, clients would need to understand what
>   it means to follow a link to retweet a status. The semantics of such a
>   service are deeper than what Fielding talks about in his comment about
>   browsers and crawlers.

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html:

> You can retrieve results for a particular search by sending an HTTP
>   GET request to its URI. The URI for a search has the following format:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?parameters

So Google's Custom Search API is an example of SOA and is NOT Restful.

True / False??

Cmon this is a clear question. why is anyone not able to answer it after 12 hours. an answer that says clearly why it is not answerable is still an answer.

Comment: I think you have the definition of SOA incorrectly.    SOA is an architectural philosophy. REST is a specific type of implementation.  I would restate your question.

Answer (score 0):

If someone builds a client that hardcodes the `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?parameters` URL then they are not using the service RESTfully.  If google do not provide a resource, that is discoverable from the service entry URL, that contains a URI template for this search URI, then it is not possible to be completely RESTful when using this API.